# Finding the Minimum Bounding Circle

Tags: geopandas, circle

I am trying to find the Minimum Bounding Circle for a given state in the US.
To do so I am using GeoPandas [minimum_bounding_circle function](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.minimum_bounding_circle.html)

The result returns a Polygon, however, I would like to find the center of the circle and the radius (in meters).
How can this be achieved?

Comment: Centroid then distance between centroid and circle border ?

Comment: @J.R I can find the Centroid easily, but what is the circle border? GeoPandas returns a Polygon, which point of the Polygon should I take?

Comment: The definition of a circle is the boundary formed by points at a certain radius from the center, so ANY of the points should be at the same distance. In fact, if they aren't, you don't have the right center point (but could find it by the midpoint of opposing vertices).

Comment: @Vince sorry, correct.
I exported the Polygon to GeoJSON and saw that it ellipse, forgot that the map is projected.
In this case, I should still work in 4326 crs?

Comment: In Shapely there is a useful function [`point_on_surface`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/maint-2.0/reference/shapely.point_on_surface.html) that can be used for calculating the radius

Comment: @Taras how point_on_surface can help calculate the radius? the center of the polygon is the centroid and the other point must be on the circle boundary.
point_on_surface returns a point which fall in the polygon (can fall inside the circle)

Comment: Apply it properly, with the `circle.exterior`